# How can I prevent Ivy from downloading multiple versions of the same dependency?

Tags: java, classpath, dependency-management, ivy

I have an `ivy.xml` file (without an `ivysettings.xml` file) with the following dependency:

```
<dependency org="org.freemarker" name="freemarker" rev="2.3.23"/>
```

However when I resolve my ivy dependencies I end up with `freemarker-2.3.8.jar` and `freemarker-2.3.23.jar`.  This is causing a problem in Apache Tomcat because the `2.3.8.jar` is taking precedence over `2.3.23.jar` and a `static final int` called `Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23` is showing up at run-time as unavailable (though it is available a compile time).  Here is the full ivy.xml in case it helps:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.example" module="ExampleProject"/>
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default">
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="java8" extends="default" description="Java 8 dependencies"/>
        <conf name="eclipse" description="Special dependencies in Eclipse"/>
        <conf name="utest" extends="eclipse" description="Unit testing dependencies"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.amazonaws" name="aws-java-sdk-s3" rev="1.10.6"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.7.10" />
        <dependency org="org.lesscss" name="lesscss" rev="1.7.0.1.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.github.mfornos" name="humanize-slim" rev="1.2.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.3.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.lambdaworks" name="scrypt" rev="1.4.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli" name="commons-cli" rev="1.2"/>
        <dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.10"/>
        <dependency org="commons-fileupload" name="commons-fileupload" rev="1.3.1"/>
        <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="2.8.1"/>
        <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.36"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1.9.6"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.4"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="4.5"/>
        <dependency org="org.freemarker" name="freemarker" rev="2.3.23"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-c3p0" rev="4.3.10.Final"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="4.3.10.Final"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-search" rev="4.5.1.Final"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-tools" rev="4.3.1.CR1"/>

        <dependency org="org.imgscalr" name="imgscalr-lib" rev="4.2"/>
        <dependency org="org.jadira.usertype" name="usertype.core" rev="3.1.0.GA"/>
        <dependency org="org.jsoup" name="jsoup" rev="1.8.3"/>
        <dependency org="org.projectlombok" name="lombok" rev="1.16.6" />
        <dependency org="org.tuckey" name="urlrewritefilter" rev="4.0.4"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"freemarker-2.3.8.jar" is part of the ["freemarker:freemarker" module](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cfreemarker%7Cfreemarker%7C2.3.8%7Cjar) and is a transitive dependency of

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-tools" rev="4.3.1.CR1"/>
```

I would recommend the following fix, telling ivy to exclude the unwanted module:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    ..
    ..    
    <dependencies>
      ..
      ..

      <exclude org="freemarker" module="freemarker"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

---

To help diagnose this problem I used the report task to analyse the content of each ivy configuration.

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <target name="resolve">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
    <ivy:report todir="reports" graph="false"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I took your answer and implemented is as `<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-tools" rev="4.3.1.CR1">
<exclude org="freemarker" module="freemarker"/></dependency>` and it works!